# Operadores += y /= con while en Python

Tags: python, algoritmos, loops, revisión-de-código, while

Estoy comenzando a estudiar Python a través de un curso en línea. Aunque he trabajado en `R` durante un par de años, y en general, creo que la programación tiene muchas bases similares, existen diferencias notables. Una de las más evidentes que he notado, es el uso, en `Python`, de operadores como: +=, *= y /=. El siguiente código, que tomé de un ejercicio del curso que comento tiene un par de esos operadores:

```
n=100
number_of_times = 0
while n >= 1:
    n /= 2
    number_of_times += 1
print(number_of_times)
```

Cuando uno corre el código, el resultado en consola es 7. La cuestión es que el ejercicio sólo pedía correr el código y anotar el resultado en la hoja de respuestas, lo cual no tiene mayor complicación.

No obstante, quisiera saber cómo "razona" el programa para que dé 7, es decir, cómo podría diseccionarse el código paso a paso para llegar a esa respuesta considerando que se utiliza un "while".

Me gustaría que alguien pudiera explicarme o darme alguna referencia al respecto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si te fijas, le estás diciendo que haga un bucle `while` mientras que `n >= 1`, es decir, cuando baje de 1 terminará e imprimirá `number_of_times`.

Por cada vuelta de bucle, se hace `n /= 2`, que es lo mismo que `n = n / 2`, es decir, divides n entre 2 y le reasignas el nuevo valor, por tanto, la primera vuelta n valdrá 50, la segunda 25, etc, etc. Resulta que en la vuelta 7 baja de 1, por tanto termina el bucle.

Si haces lo siguiente:

```
n=100
number_of_times = 0
while n >= 1:
    n /= 2
    print("n = " + str(n))
    number_of_times += 1
print("number_of_times = " + str(number_of_times))
```

Verás que imprime:

```
n = 50
n = 25
n = 12
n = 6
n = 3
n = 1
n = 0
number_of_times = 7
```

Espero haberte aclarado ;)

Comment: Totalmente aclarado. Gracias por tu tiempo y por las líneas que agregaste para hacer el código mucho más comprensible.

Comment: Con respecto a `+=`  y `/=` son operadores de asignación y todos se comportan como Imfresneda explica, la lista completa (si no me salto alguno) es: `+=`, `-= ` , `*=`, `/=`, `**=`,  `%=`y `//=` que no son más que el resultado de combinar los operadores aritméticos con `=`. Cabe destacar que la equivalencia de, por ejemplo, `a += b` no es siempre `a = a + b` (por ejemplo en objetos mutables como las listas) aunque si es cierta para inmutables como `int` o `float`.

Answer (score 1):

Si pudieramos traducir la pregunta a un pseudocódigo, se vería algo asi:

```
n empieza en 100
veces empieza en 0
mientras n sea mayor o igual que 1:
    n ahora vale la mitad de n
    sumar 1 al valor de veces
imprimir el valor de veces
```

En cada repetición del ciclo `n` va cambiando, de hecho, siempre reduciendose a la mitad. La cantidad de veces que puedes hacer esto es 7, pasando por estos numeros 50,25,12,6,3,1,0.

El único caso que te pienso que te podría causar confusión es, ¿por qué el cero? Bueno, pues es por la condición especifica de que se debe repetir el proceso hasta que `n` ya no coincida con la condición de que sea igual o mayor que 1. En este caso, cuando `n = 1`, todavia cumple la condición de mayor o igual a 1 y repite el ciclo por ultima vez, incrementando por ultima vez la variable `number_of_times`.

Comment: Lo del cero sí lo entiendo, ya que es el contador inicial (funciona de la misma forma en #R). Aprecio mucho tu tiempo para responder.

Answer (score 1):

por comenzar el código no esta identado:

```
n=100
number_of_times = 0
while n >= 1:
    n /= 2
    number_of_times += 1
print(number_of_times)
```

el while comienza con n= 100

```
n /= 2          # n queda a 50
number_of_times += 1 # number_of_times en 1
```

con n= 50

```
n /= 2          # n queda a 25
number_of_times += 1 # number_of_times en 2
```

con n= 25

```
n /= 2          # n queda a 12
number_of_times += 1 # number_of_times en 3
```

con n= 12

```
n /= 2          # n queda a 6
number_of_times += 1 # number_of_times en 4
```

con n= 6

```
n /= 2          # n queda a 3
number_of_times += 1 # number_of_times en 5
```

con n= 3

```
n /= 2          # n queda a 1
number_of_times += 1 # number_of_times en 6
```

con n= 1

```
n /= 2          # n queda a 0
number_of_times += 1 # number_of_times en 7
```